# setState not working for updating an array in React

Tags: reactjs

I try to update a `state` in a location object.
somehow the setState isn't working for me.

The `console.log` does return the newName correctly.

I don't see directly where my fault is. Can someone tell me where my error is?

```
state = {
    locations: [
       {name:"name1", address:"address1", locationSelected:false},
       {name:"name2", address:"address2", locationSelected:false}
    ]
}

selectLocationHandler = (id) => {
    let theLocations = [...this.state.locations];
    theLocations[id] = {...theLocations[id], name:"newName!!!!"};
    console.log(theLocations[id].name + "testtest");

    this.setState({theLocations}, () => {
        console.log(this.state.locations[id].name + " it worksss");
    });
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in `selectLocationHandler` function? Are you trying to handle the new item in the array?

Comment: @Liam I try to handle the state change in this function after a clickEvent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The main problem with this code is that your are altering a state object directly. You should treat all state objects as if they are immutable. In your code, you do not actually need the `setState` call because the state would already be updated. When you define `theLocations`, you are cloning the array, but not the objects in that array.

To clone an array of objects, use this:

```
const theLocations = this.state.locations.map(l => Object.assign({}, l));
```

Once you have your cloned array of objects, just set the name like this:

```
theLocations[id].name = "newName!!!!";
```

Another error here is that you are saving `theLocations` as a new property in your state object. You need to set `locations` as the key in your `setState` function:

```
this.setState({locations: theLocations}, () => {});
```

Complete code:

```
selectLocationHandler = (id) => {
    const theLocations = this.state.locations.map(l => Object.assign({}, l));
    theLocations[id].name = "newName!!!!";
    this.setState({locations: theLocations}, () => {
      console.log(this.state.locations[id].name + " it worksss");
    });
}
```

Comment: thankss a for the explenations! :-)  So when I use [...this.state.locations] i'm not cloning a array of objects? I thought with the spread syntax I can clone the elements inside the array.

Comment: Correct. It only clones the array, and not the objects inside of it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Copy_an_array

And you're welcome!

Comment: [...this.state.locations] does clone the array and objects inside it.

Comment: @Wei no, it does not clone the objects.

Comment: @KevinSmith Surely `theLocations[id] = {...theLocations[id], name:"newName!!!!"};` does create a copy of the location object?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, it does not.

Answer (score 3):

In setState you should specify name of property in the state which you want to update. In your case `{theLocations}` means that you have the next object `{theLocations: theLocations}`. You need to change it to: 

`this.setState({locations: theLocations}, () => {
  console.log(this.state.locations[id].name + " it worksss");
});`

Answer (score 0):

Reset the array to empty then set the state to the new value:

```
 this.setState({ locations: [] }, () => this.setState({ locations: theLocations }))
```