# Update Props of Component in Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that has an array of components and it doesn't seem that the component in the array is getting it's props changed.

This is an simplified example of the parent:

```
const MyParent = () => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState();
  const [viewStack, setViewStack] = useState([]);

  const handleDataChange = (newData) => {
    const newData = {
      ...foo,
      newData,
    }

    setFoo(newData);
  }

  const handleNextButton(key) {
    const currentViewStack = viewStack;
    switch(key) {
      (... several other cases here)
      case theValueWeWant:
        currentViewStack.push(<MyChildComponent myData={foo} dataChangeHandler={handleDataChange} />);
        break;
    }

    setViewStack(currentViewStack);
  }

  return ({viewStack[viewStack.length - 1]});
  
}
```

This is an simplified example of the child:

```
const MyChildComponent = (props) => {
  const [bar, setBar] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setBar(props.myData);
  }, [props.myData]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      {bar}
      <button onClick={() => { props.dataChangeHandler('my new value'); }}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

It is worthy to note that `MyChildComponent` does have children, but when I put a `useEffect` in `MyChildComponent`, it doesn't fire when the props change. (Also, we are using an array to store our components as the user progresses through a workflow, hence the `handleClickNextButton`). Here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-cloud-q0yg6?file=/src/App.js).

The problem is that when I change the data in the children of `MyChildComponent`, I pass that new data up to the parent and the state is changed but the child component does not receive new data. I have a hunch as to why, but I don't like the solution and am posting here to see if I'm missing something (and hopefully to find a better solution).

I think the problem is that I expect the props of the child component to be changed since I'm passing in a state variable. The reason it's not changing is because it's in an array (btw, I did try adding key props to the elements in the array and this didn't fix the problem). One solution is to rebuild the array every time this value changes. I don't like this for 2 reasons:

1. It seems quite ineffecient to rebuild the array on every re-render
2. It is counter intuitive. I would expect this to behave sort of like a lambda where I have access to variables in the scope the lambda is defined in (i.e. you get the global variables like `foo` within the lambda). I guess it makes sense that the values are "set" when the array is built but I was wondering if someone could provide a technical reason why this isn't possible.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in thinking the issue lies with your array state. As mentioned in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50030433/setstate-not-working-for-updating-an-array-in-react), you need to treat react state objects as **immutable**.  Since, in your code, you are directly modifying the array with `.push()`, the state object is not being properly updated.

The key here is that, whenever you're updating an object or an array that's stored in React state, you need to **create an entirely new object or array** before setting that new state.

For example:

```js
// === arrays ===
const [nums, setNums] = useState([])

// ...some code

const newNumToAddToList = 3
setNums([ ...nums, newNumToAddToList ])
// ===============

// === objects ===
const [data, setData] = useState({ initialProp: 3 })

// ...some code

const newDataProperty = 'a string value'
setData({ ...data, newProp: newDataProperty })

// or...
const newInitialPropValue = 29
setData({ initialProp: newInitialPropValue })
```

As a side note, I would **highly** recommend that you do **not** store react components in state.  A cleaner way of accomplishing your objective may be to store the underlying data in state - the `labels` in your codesandbox example.  Then, you can map these labels into components in the render method.  Here's an [example in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-rain-4msyq?file=/src/App.js)