# useState Array not Updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having a problem where an array that I have stored as a `useState` object is only getting its last element updated. In the below example, we maintain an array of objects that we update in `Sub`. If we change such a for loop to iterate through all the elements in `arr`, it is consistent behavior that the last element in `arr` will be the *only* one that gets updated.

```
function Sub({arr, setArr}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      const arr_copy = arr.slice()
      arr_copy[i] = i
      setArr(arr_copy)
    }
  },[])
  return <p> </p>
}

export function App(props) {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState(["NOT CHANGED","NOT CHANGED"])


  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {arr.map((d) => <p> {d} </p>)}
      <Sub arr={arr} setArr = {setArr}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Renders:

```
NOT CHANGED

1
```

I've tried the suggested answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50030433/setstate-not-working-for-updating-an-array-in-react) thread - these all being different variations of "pass in a callback to the setfunction", "first set the array to an empty array," "create deep copy" and none of these seem to work (all resulting in the same behavior of the last element of the array being the only one changed).

As a further note I get the same behavior for `useState({...})` where I populate and update a dictionary as opposed to a list.

Comment: it has nothing to do with useState, every iteration you are creating a new array and changing one item, if you console.log arr_copy before setArr(arr_copy) you will see what happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the `useState` its your own code.

on the first line inside of the for loop you define a new array so every time its a new array with the same values as the original array.

let me explain this with step by step guide:

```
i = 0: 
1 - arr_copy = ["NOT CHANGED","NOT CHANGED"] 
2 - arr_copy = [0,"NOT CHANGED"]
3 - setArray([0,"NOT CHANGED"])

i = 1: 
1 - arr_copy = ["NOT CHANGED","NOT CHANGED"] 
2 - arr_copy = ["NOT CHANGED", 1]
3 - setArray(["NOT CHANGED", 1])
```

Comment: But when I run `setArray([0, "NOT CHANGED"])`, does this not update the value for `arr`, such that when I next access it, it has been modified? I thought perhaps this was a async issue but adding an `await` before `setArray(...)` does not solve the problem

Comment: It does but the `useEffect` that you wrote has `[]` as its second argument so the for loop executes just once.

Comment: Also await does not work on `setState` method.